# How do I output from a PowerShell script (PSObjects?) to a WinForms TextBox in real-time?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, powershell

I am executing a PowerShell script from a Visual Basic WinForms UI, and I managed to code it so it executes on a BackgroundWorker thread so that the UI doesn't lock up while the script is running. What it does is imports a .printerExport file to add printers and drivers to a target host, and it runs great. The only issue is that I set the output of the PSObjects to a TextBox and they all get output at the end once the script is completed, rather than output in real time like it would in a PowerShell console window.

I have tried multiple things to get it to output in real-time, but I am out of ideas, and even ReportProgress doesn't manage to get the real-time output as well.

How can I get this done? Below are the three involved Sub functions I am currently using:

```
    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

        Dim HostName As String
        Dim PrintName As String
        Dim SourceFilePath As String
        Dim DestinationPath As String
        Dim FileName As String

        HostName = txtHostName.Text
        PrintName = "\\" & txtHostName.Text
        SourceFilePath = txtFilePath.Text
        DestinationPath = PrintName & "\c$\Temp\"

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(HostName) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceFilePath) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the target host name and choose a file path.")
            Return
        End If

        FileName = Path.GetFileName(SourceFilePath)

        File.Copy(SourceFilePath, Path.Combine(DestinationPath, Path.GetFileName(SourceFilePath)), True)

        Dim PsEnv As New RunspaceInvoke
        Dim App As String = $"Invoke-Command -ComputerName {HostName} {{C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\Printbrm.exe -r -s {PrintName} -f ""C:\Temp\{FileName}""}}"
        Dim AppObjects As Collection(Of PSObject) = PsEnv.Invoke(App)
        Dim Output As New StringBuilder()
        Dim id As Integer = 0

        For Each psobj2 As PSObject In AppObjects
            id += 1
            BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(id, psobj2.ToString() & vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
        Next

    End Sub



    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged

        Dim userState As String = CType(e.UserState, String)
        TextBox3.AppendText(userState)

    End Sub



    Private Sub buttonInstall_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles buttonInstall.Click

        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Every seems in order to me on a quick glance, bout the on question I can get to is what is TextBox3?  Is that a standard text box control, or something else?  Maybe it's just a case of setting the insertion point to the end after appending the text

Comment: It is a standard TextBox control, yes. What do you mean by setting the insertion point to the end after appending the text?

Comment: Anyone here know a solution to this issue I am having? Still haven't been able to figure it out.